# i18next-json-sync usage issue

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I am trying to use `i18next-json-sync` npm package to sync different language files for my angular2/nodejs project. But the given usage is not working for me.

My lang file structure is:

```
-package.json
-public
  |-app
    |-assets
        |-language
            |-en.json
            |-es.json
            |-fr.json
            |-ja.json
```

The package.json has:

```
{ 
 "scripts": {
  ...
  "i18n": "sync-i18n --files './public/app/assets/language/*.json' --primary en --languages es fr ja",
  "check-i18n": "npm run i18n -- --check",

  ...
}
 "devDependencies": {
   ...
   "i18next-json-sync": "2.2.0",
   ...
 }
}
```

But when I run `npm run check-i18n` or `npm run i18n` I do not see any key/values being copied from en file (primary) to other language files.

Comment: I know the question is about that sync lib - but as the maintainer of i18next i just like to give you another option that also supports the future development of i18next -> did you already check out https://locize.com ?!? Would be a more efficient way to do the localization job with i18next.

Comment: I did not know about this lib. I will check it out. But my organization has in-house staff to do the translation. The challenge is only to keep all json files in sync in case they forget to enter a string in one of the files. So sync lib would be an over-engineering for that.

Comment: on locize.com you don't need to order translations - it's more about managing them -> progress control, plural conversion, ... you still can invite your own translators to a project there. You might give the 14d free trial a try - no risk, no creditcard needed, no obligations ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem is quite old but found the solution:
So, your path shouldn't be surrounded by ' '. therefore your code should look like this:

```
"i18n": "sync-i18n --files ./public/app/assets/language/*.json --primary en --languages es fr ja",
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still need a proper solution (which works)

[i18next-locales-sync](https://github.com/felixmosh/i18next-locales-sync) is my lib which I wrote since the lib you’ve mentioned doesn't work with namespaces & doesn't has a proper plural support.

```sh
npx i18next-locales-sync -p he -s en de ja -l path/to/locales/folder
```